# Do Until loop in VBA does not break on Exit Sub

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote the following code in order to ask for an input.

```
validInput = False
Do
    str = InputBox("Some text...")
    If str = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox ("Input canceled")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If IsNumeric(str) Then
            exchange = CCur(str)
            validInput = True
        Else
            MsgBox ("Input invalid.")
        End If
    End If
Loop Until validInput
```

However, if I cancel my input it keeps asking me for an input and the loop goes on even though I added the `Exit Sub` line.

I tried to add `validInput = True` before `Exit Sub` but that didn't work either.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
Here is the whole sub.

```
Public Sub CurrencyCheck()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Datenbank")
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim curSymbol As String
Dim exchange As Currency
Dim str As String
Dim curArr() As String
Dim arrCnt As Integer
arrCnt = 1
Dim curInArr As Boolean
curInArr = False
Dim curIndex As Integer
Dim validInput As Boolean

ReDim curArr(1 To 2, 1 To arrCnt)

For i = 1 To lastRow
    If ws.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "Price" And ws.Cells(i, 4).Value <> "" Then
        curSymbol = Get_Currency(ws.Cells(i, 4).text) 'Function that returns currency symbol (€) or abbreviation (EUR)
        If curSymbol <> "€" Then
            For j = LBound(curArr, 2) To UBound(curArr, 2)
                If curArr(1, j) = curSymbol Then
                    curInArr = True
                    curIndex = j
                End If
            Next j
            If Not curInArr Then
                If curSymbol = "EUR" Then
                    ReDim Preserve curArr(1 To 2, 1 To arrCnt)
                    curArr(1, arrCnt) = curSymbol
                    curArr(2, arrCnt) = 1
                    curIndex = arrCnt
                    arrCnt = arrCnt + 1
                Else
                    validInput = False
                    Do Until validInput
                        str = InputBox("Some text...")
                        If str = vbNullString Then
                            MsgBox ("Input canceled.")
                            Exit Sub
                        Else
                            If IsNumeric(str) Then
                                exchange = CCur(str)
                                validInput = True
                            Else
                                MsgBox ("Input invalid.")
                            End If
                        End If
                    Loop
                    ReDim Preserve curArr(1 To 2, 1 To arrCnt)
                    curArr(1, arrCnt) = curSymbol
                    curArr(2, arrCnt) = exchange
                    curIndex = arrCnt
                    arrCnt = arrCnt + 1
                End If
            End If
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = StringToCurrency(ws.Cells(i, 4).text)
            ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = ws.Cells(i, 4).Value * curArr(2, curIndex)
            ws.Cells(i, 4).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 €"
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT2:** When I run the input loop as a subroutine by itself it works. The macro is run in another workbook and doing that it fails...

**EDIT3:** My bad. The problem is not related to the code but to the positioning of the subroutine. It was called of and over again because it was called in a loop. I have to apologize. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Change `Do` to `Do until validInput = true` and take out `loop until...` and just put `loop`. Try that

Comment: Works fine in my Excel 2010. You might want to change the restricted *str* to something else though. You might want to try `GoTo EndSub1` in lieu of `Exit Sub`.

Comment: @Sam No, doesn't work. @user3819867 I use Excel desktop from the Office365 package and it doesn't work. What should I change `str` to? I want to have a currency value in the end. I rather not use `GoTo` and it should work with the code I used, right? Just, that it doesn't...

Comment: This code snippet works fine. Maybe you could add some more code where this code snippet is used?

Comment: Done. Added the complete sub.

Comment: Change `exit sub` to `exit do`

Comment: If you are calling it from another workbook. Wouldn't the exit sub exit the sub that called this macro. So the loop would still exist due to the being open still. Someone correct me if I am wrong

Comment: And how exactly are you calling the procedure ```CurrencyCheck()```?

Comment: @Sam Not sure, but as I start a new sub it should exit that sub instead of the sub it was called from, right? @dee Inside another sub, like this `Call CurrencyCheck`.

Comment: TBH I am not totally sure. Couldnt find much online about it. But if it just sends the command to exit sub in what ever sub it is running then it might just close the wrong one down. Try doing `Exit Do` as this should just exit from the do loop. You can test to see which sub it will exit by adding like a message box after the call in your other workbook. If that message box gets called then it is exiting the right one. If it does not then the sub which calls the other sub is exiting

Comment: Wow, even changing `Exit Sub` to `Exit Do` and then adding `If validInput = False Then Exit Sub` doesn't work. Still keeps me in the loop.

Comment: This is very very strange. Something is keeping that loop alive some how. I am going to try and replicate it and see if I come accross that problem

Comment: How do you call it from the other workbook? Is it `application.run`?

Comment: @Sam It gets better. I tried a `While`-loop. Same, didn't work. THEN I tried to delete the loop. Still the same. Now there isn't even a loop anymore. Still gives me the input query again after I pressed `cancel`. To call it from another workbook I use the "Macros"-button in the developer-ribbon.

Comment: Maybe change the name `str` as it is a built in function. So not sure how office 365 works. Maybe that is the reason for the conflict as I have tried to replicate it but failed. I have taken just the loop in one workbook. Then used another workbook to call that sub and works fine

Comment: Try exiting the loop with another condition. Like `Do Until validInput or failedInput` then instead of `exit sub` put `failedInput=true` and after the loop put something like if `failedInput = true then exit sub`

Comment: Nothing works. This is weird... If I go through the code in debug mode everything works correctly and the sub exits after the `Exit Sub` line. If I select the macro from the macros menu though and click cancel it just shows me the `InputBox` again and again and again...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77091/discussion-between-moritz-schmitz-v-hulst-and-sam).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will loop until a numeric is entered:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim validInput As Boolean
    Dim strg As String, x As Variant
    validInput = False
    Do
        strg = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter value", Type:=2)
        If strg = "False" Then
        ElseIf IsNumeric(strg) Then
            x = CCur(strg)
            validInput = True
        End If
    Loop Until validInput
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will quit the loop if the user touches the <kbd>CANCEL</kbd> button or the red **x** button:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim validInput As Boolean
    Dim strg As String, x As Variant
    validInput = False
    Do
        strg = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="enter value", Type:=2)
        If strg = "False" Or strg = "" Then
            validInput = True
        ElseIf IsNumeric(strg) Then
            x = CCur(strg)
            validInput = True
        End If
    Loop Until validInput
End Sub
```

Comment: They already have their loop to look for numbers. The problem is that the loop does not end if they cancel it...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is a null string. Try this

```
If str = vbNullString or str = "" Then
```

Comment: It would be a `vbnullstring` if nothing ever gets set to it

Comment: And I am sure it is a `vbNullString` because the output is correct. As in it shows me the correct `MsgBox`.